# Обращение к БД Postgresql из функции в Go

Tags: postgresql, golang, веб-сервер

Добрый день!
Прошу помощи! 
Никак не получается обратиться к базе данных Postgresql из другой функции после установления соединения.

```
package main

import (
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        _ "github.com/lib/pq"
       )

var db *sql.DB

// инициализируем соединение с БД
func init() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://user:password@remote_ip:5432/main?sslmode=disable")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Ошибка, %s", err)
    }

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Ошибка ping, %s", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Open connections: %d\n", db.Stats().OpenConnections)
}
```

При обращении через созданный web-сервер по пути "/" падает со следующей ошибкой:

```
http: panic serving [::1]:57957: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 20 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc04204aa00)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1697 +0xd7
panic(0x68e8c0, 0x855f00)
```

Как будто он не видит соединения или оно сразу закрывается. При запуске всё в пределах одной функции всё работает нормально.
А при разносе по разным функциям возникает данная ошибка. Что я не так делаю? Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://user:password@remote_ip:5432/main?sslmode=disable")
```

Вот тут вы создаёте новую переменную вместо присваивания старой. Делайте так:

```
var err error
db, err = sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://user:password@remote_ip:5432/main?sslmode=disable")
```

Comment: Я в шоке. Проглядел все глаза, а это присвоение не заметил! Спасибо!